# What's the precedence of TypeScript operators?

Tags: typescript

When writing complex types in TypeScript, the different operators have a certain precedence.

For example, this code:

```
typeof map[T]
```

Intuitively, we could think that it is equivalent of:

```
typeof (map[T])
```

But it's actually equivalent to:

```
(typeof map)[T]
```

Which means that the `typeof` operator has higher precedence than the square brackets, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Is there a precedence order table with all the keywords : `extends`, `infer`, `keyof`, `typeof`, etc?

Comment: There's the outdated spec which shows [the grammar for types](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3821ef011ada48c14e07e3124c6502a44a3e3856/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#a1-types), which wouldn't have `infer` and doesn't explicitly spell out the precedence in human-friendly order; there's an open feature request at [ms/TS#7094](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7094) to put this in the docs, but it's in the backlog so I doubt it will happen anytime soon.  And people might even change it [ms/TS#19707](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19707).

Comment: I could put this into an answer, which is the closest to an "authoritative" answer I can think of.  Otherwise it's just someone experimenting with expressions to empirically determine the precedence, or looking through the type checker code.  Pragmatically, ambiguity should be resolved through parentheses and the actual order is interesting but not of vital importance (in my opinion).  Maybe someone else will come along and go through the exercise of determining the actual rules

Comment: It's up to you, but if you believe it to be authoritative I think it would be relevant to write it as an answer

Comment: `typeof` is specifically only legal on "identifiers (i.e. variable names) or their properties" ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#limitations)). So in any situation where `typeof a[b]` is syntactically ambiguous, `b` must be a literal value, in which case it is also a literal type and the result is the same regardless of operator precedence. If `b` is an identifier instead, then according to the docs, it cannot be parsed as `typeof (a[b])` because `typeof` is not legal on that kind of expression.

Comment: Other than that, I cannot think of any situation where multiple Typescript type operators could be syntactically ambiguous - even if there is no precedence order table, can you give any example involving (say) `extends` and `infer` where you would *need* one?

Comment: I actually don't, but there are ambiguous expressions, like the ones based on the intersect and union operators